# How do I upgrade to the gatling gun?

Tags: civilization-5

I am playing on Civ V from Steam on my Ubuntu (Linux) OS.

I am playing the English nation and use the longbowman with pleasure. I [read on the wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Gatling_gun_(Civ5)) that this unit can upgrade to Gatling gun and keep its range bonus. I can't find the Gatling gun in my version of the game. The longbowman seems to upgrade to rifleman. More over, the Gatling gun need Industrialization tech which does exist on my version.

Do I need a mod/extension for this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes you do. You need the Gods & Kings expansion pack.**

It states directly on the wiki page of the Gatling Gun that it was:

> Introduced in Gods & Kings

(found under the image in the wiki link you posted)

**Some information about the Gods & Kings expansion pack:**

> Sid Meier's Civilization® V: Gods & Kings is the first expansion pack released for Civilization V. It was released June 19, 2012 in North America and June 22, 2012 worldwide. As the name shows, the expansion focuses on a brand new feature - Religion, which adds a whole new level of development for a civilization.

[Source](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Gods_%26_Kings)

Comment: Ah ok! Now I now where to look for next time, thank's. The longbowman page could be improved by specifying on which version of the game it upgrades to Gatling gun and should always have the default upgrade to for the basic game.

Answer (score 2):

The Gatling Gun was added by the [Gods & Kings](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Gods_%26_Kings) expansion. This is actually stated underneath the image on the right hand side of the page you linked to:

[image]